# [PrimeReact - InputText]How to Display Hyperlink in InputText element of PrimeReact

Tags: hyperlink, primereact

I am trying to display hyperlink (anchor tag) on a PrimeReact's InputText element. Is there a way i can do that?. I did try to lookup on google as wells on sandbox, i couldn't find any example that displays a hyperlink on a InputText element.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense InputText is an input component and HyperLink is a navigation component. Can you explain more about your use case and what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hello Melloware

Thank you for responding to my question and sorry for the delay on the response.

You are correct, but i have a case, where in the Add mode, user can enter some Text in a InputText Element. Now if that text Contains some pattern like service ticket number, then on the Display mode the same InputText box is protected, but if the Text contains a Ticket number, then just the Ticket Number should display as a Hyperlink, that user can click on to, so that i can navigate to the details of the Ticket, which could be different site/url.

Comment: OK I don't think you want to render it as a disable input you want to render it differently so you can display the hyperlink and Text.  Have you looked at the Inplace component: https://primefaces.org/primereact/inplace/ it seems more like what you need?

Comment: That's great 
Malloware

Thank you so much for your help .Let me try to take a look at that